# SHAP local_accuracy

Tags: python, shap

When calculating local_accuracy from metrics.py I got the following error :

**NameError: name 'pickle' is not defined**

```
from shap.benchmark import metrics
metrics.local_accuracy(X, y, poly_svr,"tree" )
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1IRl.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Did you read the traceback?  Did you then do `pip install dill`?

Comment: `dill` is imported as `pickle` in SHAP. Try installing `dill` and see if this helps.

Comment: I actually did install dill but I kept getting the same error and it appears like the package did not correctly install so reinstalling it fixed the problem , thanks